# How to detect movie preloaded/failed on iOS4?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

In 3.0, I could register for `MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification` and detect if the movie preloaded or failed, depending on whether there was an error object.  Can anyone tell me the equivalent of the two cases for iOS4?

[**Update**: Responding to the first comment here because the max comment length is too short.]

If you successfully play a movie on iOS4, you get:

- `MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification` with no error object (deprecated)
- `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` and `player.loadState=MPMovieLoadStatePlayable`
- `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` and `player.loadState=MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK`

If it fails (for instance because of an incorrect URL), you get:

- `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` `loadState=MPMovieLoadStateUnknown`

And that's it.  No `MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification` with an error object like in 3.0, no `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`.  So is the only way to detect a failed load to inspect the player.`loadState` for `MPMovieLoadStateUnknown` in `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`?

It seems counterintuitive, to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Register for the `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` notification, and then check the `loadState` property of the `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Source: [ADC Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html)